# Create secure API communication

Tags: php, mysql, api

I am looking to build an API that I can deploy on my servers to monitor system load.
It will report to a central manager server that runs a client to display the information.

The issue I am struggling with is best to secure the API.
What I want is for the client to be the only software that can access the server and retrieve this information but I am unsure how to achieve this using PHP.
I also want the possibility of distributing the API and client for others to use on their servers so I don't want people to be able to access other people data if they are using the API also.

The client is also written in PHP using MySql and has a secure login.

Comment: Consider using SSL/TLS.

Comment: Yeah I did think of that but people can still access the url and get the data, I suppose I could restrict access and require a certain IP address but that's not very flexible.

Comment: Have you considered using API keys?

Comment: @bobthemac Authorization (restrict on IP) and authentication (using API keys) is not uncommon if you want to protect this web service.

Comment: Will API keys mean I can only access the API with the software

Comment: @bob no, they won't. In the end, you can't guarantee which software the client is using. Any traffic between your software and the API can be re-engineered. That said, why is it such a problem in the first place? As long as you use authentication, why do you care which tool your users use to access the API?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I care because I want users to use my tool and the information I am sending will be identifying information about the server that I would rather I was in control of.

Comment: @bob if the information is sensitive and the client shouldn't see it, you shouldn't send it. If you have access to the client locally, any traffic can be sniffed and re-engineered if you put enough effort in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

> I also want the possibility of distributing the API and client for others to use on their servers so I don't want people to be able to access other people data if they are using the API also.

The only right answer to this is **authentication**. You need to protect your API by giving each user access credentials known only to them.

Your API must **never** reveal any data that the client isn't allowed to see as per their authentication credentials. Trying to work around this danger by trying to somehow protect the client from prying eyes is **not safe** - somebody who has access to the client and can observe it running will be able to reverse engineer any traffic between it and the server given enough effort.

If the API is properly secured, it won't matter to you which client tool is used to access it. The requirement to limit API access to a certain *program* will go away.

Comment: I already have access credentials on the client but the API will run on a totally different server, Are we talking about public and private keys assigned to users.

Comment: @bob if you already have authentication, why is the prospect of somebody accessing the API with something different than *your* specific client such a problem then? What could happen if they used their own tool to access your API? After all, the access credentials already prevent misuse. Don't they?

Comment: The api is completely separate it runs as a separate service on a different server. The client is what will be used to access the API and that's what's got the authentication.

Comment: @bob yeah, that's the way remote APIs usually work. So what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is I only want users that have accounts on my client to be able to access the API on the other server.

Comment: @bobthemac so they register their accounts with your *client* and not the API, and that registration then decides whether they get to access the API or not? And the client runs on their servers? That's a completely broken concept security-wise. If I wanted to gain access to your API, I would simply look at what the client does (using a network sniffer or by looking at your client's PHP code), and replicate its actions. You can make your client send some secret code that makes it *hard* to use the API outside the client, but making it *impossible* may not be possible at all.

Comment: Would it not make more sense if the users registered their accounts with the API, and entered the credentials into your client? Because then it would no longer matter to you whether they use your client to use the API, or something else.

Comment: Could I do that over multiple server the reason I ask is the whole point of the API is to give system information to a client the API would run on every server to give details like cpu and memory usage for the server it is running on.

Comment: @bob I'm not sure whether we are understanding each other... again, if you use authentication, I don't think there is a reason why you would need to restrict access to *your* client. The username and password will already make sure nobody can misuse the data.

Comment: Yeh I don't think we get each other. What I am trying to say is the API and the client are both separate I would see them as different sites. The client accesses the API as a different service or site that gives data about the server it is running on.

Comment: @bob yeah. I understand that, but I don't get what it has to do with your question (ie. why you need to make sure it's your client using the API). Maybe that is the key here

Comment: simply all I want is people not to be able to open the link in there browser and get the data. I may have asked the wrong question or worded it badly.

Answer (score 0):

if you use SSL, along with authentication (i use 3rd party auth google, fb, etc), create data /reports on the fly and have the data saved in a subdirectory OUTSIDE your web folder (instead of /var/www, /var/myStorage/currentSessionId/), then you basically guarantee the security that you want.

your php will only access a subdir that is named for the session it is running under.